# Get exact date and time for a push notification on an iOS device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Is there a way we can intercept push notification messages sent to my app and log the exact date and time at which it was finally received by the iOS device?

I am using Urban Airship for my push notifications and this is a mission critical app which involves many middle layers so I want to know the exact latency between my first and my last layer (iOS device)